# Removing "submitted by <username>" InfoPath through Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

Everyone, This is truly annoying.  I created a custom list in SharePoint 2010.  Customized it as a form using InfoPath 2010 and added the submit action button to send an email.  Saved the work and published back to the list.

Everything works as designed....except that the email generated has the "submitted by " and we need this to be anonymous.

Even worse, when seen from a blackberry or hand-held – it even tells the real sender as ReplyTo: .  So even though the email is from the Sharepoint web admin account, but when you reply the email – it shows up the actual sender.

How do we set this up so that the email generated can really be Anonymous.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Okay the trick is to create an anonymous website first and create / publish the InfoPath form there in the library. Make sure it is web browser enabled and anonymous permissions set.  And then reference this anonymous form from your NT authenticated portal. I made a good use of the Page Viewer and embedded the link as given below to open the form when the page loads.

How to setup (SharePoint 2010):

1. Navigate to Central Admin and click on Manage web applications
2. Click New and give the site a name and port number.  Be sure to set it to allow anonymous access and click Ok
3. Click on the link Create Site Collection in the Application Created window
4. Fill out the required data and click Ok
5. Ok
6. Navigate to the new site that was created above
7. Go to Site Actions and choose Site Settings
8. Click on Site permissions
9. Click Anonymous Access in the ribbon and set it to Entire Web site and click Ok
10. Click on Site Actions and click View All Site Content
11. Click Create
12. Select Form Library, give it a name and click Create
13. When the library opens click on Library Settings and then click on Advanced Settings
    Be sure the library is set to open the form in the browser and click Ok
14. Design your template and publish it to the new library created above
15. On the authenticated site create or modify a link and paste the ULR to the browser form on the anonymous site using the following format for the URL:  http://anonymousportal:7307/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=/testlibrary/forms/template.xsn

If you require further help, please do not hesitate to contact me. Hope this is helpful.